# Why GAE go runtime 1.11 max concurrent requests not working?

Tags: google-app-engine, go

Since moving to GAE go runtime 1.11, we notice the number of instances is much higher. When I dig into the problem, it seems that GAE is not running in concurrency.

Here is a very light module of the frontend settings:

```
automatic_scaling:
  min_idle_instances: 1
  max_idle_instances: 2
  min_pending_latency: 0.030s
  max_pending_latency: automatic
  max_concurrent_requests: 80
  target_throughput_utilization: 0.95
```

And with about 50 requests per second, GAE spun up 2 active instances. Each has about 25 QPS and the average latency is under 20ms. Even the chart shows the instances aren't really busy.

What is in the settings that would cause this issue?

I don't think Go runtime 1.9 has this issue. And the document said it ignores the max concurrent requests setting which should make Go runtime 1.11 perform much better.

Answer (score 0):

The `max_pending_latency: automatic` setting will make your app to scale up if your latency goes above 30ms . If in the current situation, with 2 instances, your average latency is somewhat under 20, it would have been possible that in the initial situation it went over 30 for a short period of time, which triggered the scaling. In case you do not want this to happen, you can always set the `max_pending_latency` manually, with a value above 30.

Regarding the comparison with Go 1.9, it is known that Go 1.11 consumes slightly more RAM and CPU power than his ancestor, so this would be something normal.

In conclusion I do not think that what is happening in your situation is an issue, but something normal. In case you do not agree you can provide me your whole, sanitized `app.yaml` file and I will look deeper to see if anything is wrong and edit my answer.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. It's interesting that `max_pending_latency` would behave similarly to `min_pending_latency` when it's `automatic`.

I thought that because of the concurrent settings, it will need somewhere close to 70 QPS to trigger another instance. So the pending latency settings is not concurrent?

Comment: max_pending_latency it is related to the latency of each of your instances. But what I was saying is that the concurrency works properly and there is not an issue at all. You are just consuming a bit more resources and the autoscaling is triggered. Could you confirm that this is the situation ?

Comment: When migrated to Go 1.11 with minimal code changes (folder structure, use appengine.Mian()), the memory consumption was doubled. It was quite a big jump. Now we changed the structure a lot and it's getting close to the cost of 1.9. But what's puzzling is that the concurrency settings don't seem working as what we expect. So we are trying to understand how it works and tune those settings, because the instances don't seem very busy at all.

Comment: I understand your concern, but I think your concurrency settings are working fine. If you use max_pending_latency : automatic, each time one of your instances reaches 30 ms, your system is scaling up. If one of your instances has 30ms latency, that means busy. Try to tune your setting regarding max/min latency rather then the concurrency ones.